# SqlMetaData not supported in ASP.NET 5

Tags: ado.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to use SqlMetaData in ASP.NET 5. I am getting error that is not supported in ASP.NET 5 Core.

Am I missing some .NET Core DLL reference or SqlMetaData is really not supported?
I need it for passing UDT table SqlDataRecord to SQL Server Procedure to improve performance of my web app.
My project.json looks like this :

```
 "frameworks": {


        "net45": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Data.Common": "1.0.0-beta1",
                "System.Data.SqlClient": "1.0.0-beta1"
            },
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
            }

        },

        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Data.Common": "1.0.0-beta1",
                "System.Data.SqlClient": "1.0.0-beta1"
            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22605",
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22523",
                "System.Data.Common": "4.0.0.0-beta-22605",
                "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.0.0.0-beta-22605",
                "Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.1.0-beta1"
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting exception on .NET Core:
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData' threw an exception: **Type Udt is not supported on this platform.**

Comment: Which packages do you currently have referenced for using SQL Server on .Net Core?

Comment: I have just edited question and included referenced packages.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [unofficial Reverse Package Search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=SqlMetaData), it looks like you can find `SqlMetaData` in `System.Data.SqlClient`. Using ILSpy, I was able to find it under `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server` in the cached `%USERPROFILE%\.k\packages\System.Data.SqlClient\4.0.0-beta-22605\lib\aspnetcore50\System.Data.SqlClient.dll` - looks like it is in `System.Data.Common` for aspnetcore50.

However, it looks like you're using an older version of the package specifically for your .Net 4.5 and Asp.Net 5 references; **I'd recommend moving your dependencies for `System.Data.SqlClient` out to the platform-agnostic area, or at least updating the references** if you want to continue using the .Net 4.5 framework assembly for that platform. (The package does include the dll for net45 and aspnetcore50.)

Here's how I structured my project.json; I removed the irrelevant lines. Note that I got an error for aspnet50 and net45 before I added the "frameworkAssemblies" reference for "aspnet50" and "net45". (You'll want to add back in your Newtonsoft reference, probably to the general dependencies above, but the other System.Data.* references will automatically get included thanks to the hierarchical references supported in the new versions.)

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.0.0-beta-22605"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "net45": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        },
        "aspnet50": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for answer. I do need .NET 4.5 for this assembly. I have updated these packages to 1.0.0-beta2 but no success. My problem is that I cannot run project on aspnetcore50. On mouse over SqlMetaData I am getting aspnetcore50 - not available I can run project on ASP.NET 5 but not on ASP.NET 5 Core

Comment: Also I have opened same DLL-s using Telerik JustDecompile. in .k\packages\System.Data.SqlClient\4.0.0-beta-22605\lib\aspnetcore50\System.Data.SqlClient.dll you only have _SqlMetaData class with underscore which is not SqlMetaData class I guess?

Comment: I updated my answer to be more clear; make sure you're using the latest version of the System.Data.SqlClient for all platforms. I was able to make a reference to `SqlMetaData` - it is in the DLL, but most of the search tools (whether IL Spy or Telerik JustDecompile) aren't finding classes in the new DLL properly; you can browse to it directly, however, at least in IL Spy.

Comment: I have changed project.json but I am still getting error Type Udt is not supported on this platform (added additional info in question). Also still when I mouseOver on SqlMetaData I am getting aspnetcore - not available. It seams that this class not existis in .NET Core...

Comment: That's odd, I hadn't run into a situation yet where the type initializer failed. I'd recommend opening an issue on github (https://github.com/aspnet) for the team since it's still in development. It also may already be fixed for beta-4, so you could wait and see.